# Power BI date difference from different tables without relationship

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have `Date1` from table `A` and `Date2` from table `B` and I want to calculate a measure as

```
DATEDIFF(A[Date1],  B[Date2], Days)
```

FYI Table `A` and Table `B` are not related (no relationship exists)

I'm not able to use the above measure. Is there any other way where I can achieve the result as per my scenario?

Comment: Is there only one row for each date column?

Comment: @AlexisOlson No there are multiple rows

Comment: Then which dates in the column do you want to use?